# How can I train a UNET model with 4 auxiliary output of varying shapes with tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

**My problem**
I am investigating the impact of auxiliary outputs on UNets for microscopic cell detection and counting but have been stuck with a bug for over a week now. Unfortunately, most documentation online hasn't helped.

My auxiliary outputs( *aux1, aux 2 and aux3*) use various intermediate blocks of the UNet model as inputs which all produce outputs with different shapes unlike that from the *original* UNet model which uses an input size of (256,256,3) to produce an output of (256,256,1). These auxiliary outputs are then used to train the model.
So the main challenge is how to declare these during training, so it considers this. Have tried modifying my generator function as well as my code but no success. Will be grateful if anyone can help.

**Error Message obtained:**
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected aux1 to have shape (32, 32, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 1)

**Model Summary:**

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)            (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_92 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32) 864         input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_92 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 32) 128         conv2d_92[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_92 (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           batch_normalization_92[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_22 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           activation_92[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_93 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 64) 18432       max_pooling2d_22[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_93 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         conv2d_93[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_93 (Activation)      (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           batch_normalization_93[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           activation_93[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_94 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 128)  73728       max_pooling2d_23[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_94 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         conv2d_94[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_94 (Activation)      (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           batch_normalization_94[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           activation_94[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_95 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  589824      max_pooling2d_24[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_95 (BatchNo (None, 32, 32, 512)  2048        conv2d_95[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_95 (Activation)      (None, 32, 32, 512)  0           batch_normalization_95[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_22 (UpSampling2D) (None, 64, 64, 512)  0           activation_95[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_22 (Concatenate)    (None, 64, 64, 640)  0           up_sampling2d_22[0][0]           
                                                                 activation_94[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_96 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 128)  737280      concatenate_22[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_96 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         conv2d_96[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_96 (Activation)      (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           batch_normalization_96[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_23 (UpSampling2D) (None, 128, 128, 128 0           activation_96[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_23 (Concatenate)    (None, 128, 128, 192 0           up_sampling2d_23[0][0]           
                                                                 activation_93[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_97 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 64) 110592      concatenate_23[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_97 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         conv2d_97[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_97 (Activation)      (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           batch_normalization_97[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_99 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 32)   147456      activation_95[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_101 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   36864       activation_96[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_103 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 32) 18432       activation_97[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_99 (BatchNo (None, 32, 32, 32)   128         conv2d_99[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_101 (BatchN (None, 64, 64, 32)   128         conv2d_101[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_103 (BatchN (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_103[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_24 (UpSampling2D) (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           activation_97[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_99 (Activation)      (None, 32, 32, 32)   0           batch_normalization_99[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_101 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           batch_normalization_101[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_103 (Activation)     (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_103[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_24 (Concatenate)    (None, 256, 256, 96) 0           up_sampling2d_24[0][0]           
                                                                 activation_92[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_100 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 32)   9216        activation_99[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_102 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   9216        activation_101[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_104 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 32) 9216        activation_103[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_98 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32) 27648       concatenate_24[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_100 (BatchN (None, 32, 32, 32)   128         conv2d_100[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_102 (BatchN (None, 64, 64, 32)   128         conv2d_102[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_104 (BatchN (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_104[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_98 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 32) 128         conv2d_98[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_100 (Activation)     (None, 32, 32, 32)   0           batch_normalization_100[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_102 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           batch_normalization_102[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_104 (Activation)     (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_104[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_98 (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           batch_normalization_98[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
aux1 (Conv2D)                   (None, 32, 32, 1)    33          activation_100[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
aux2 (Conv2D)                   (None, 64, 64, 1)    33          activation_102[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
aux3 (Conv2D)                   (None, 128, 128, 1)  33          activation_104[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
original (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 1)  33          activation_98[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,793,508
Trainable params: 1,791,204
Non-trainable params: 2,304
```

**My Model**

```
...
weight_decay = 1e-5
K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')

def _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = (1,1)):
    def f(input):
        conv_a = Conv2D(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = subsample,
                               init = 'orthogonal', 
                               border_mode='same', bias = False)(input)
        norm_a = BatchNormalization()(conv_a)
        act_a = Activation(activation = 'relu')(norm_a)
        return act_a
    return f

 def _conv_bn_relu_x2(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = (1,1)):
    def f(input):
        conv_a = Convolution2D(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = subsample,
                               init = 'orthogonal', border_mode = 'same',bias = False,
                               W_regularizer = l2(weight_decay),
                               b_regularizer = l2(weight_decay))(input)
        norm_a = BatchNormalization()(conv_a)
        act_a = Activation(activation = 'relu')(norm_a)
        conv_b = Convolution2D(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = subsample,
                               init = 'orthogonal', border_mode = 'same',bias = False,
                               W_regularizer = l2(weight_decay),
                               b_regularizer = l2(weight_decay))(act_a)
        norm_b = BatchNormalization()(conv_b)
        act_b = Activation(activation = 'relu')(norm_b)
        return act_b
    return f

def U_net_Multi_base(input, dropout = None):
    nb_filter = 32
    kernel_size = (3,3)
    block1 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter, 3,3)(input)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(block1)
    # =========================================================================
    block2 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter*2, 3,3)(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block2)
    # =========================================================================
    block3 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter*4, 3,3)(pool2)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block3)
    # =========================================================================
    block4 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter*16, 3,3)(pool3)
    if dropout:
        block4 = Dropout(dropout)(block4)
    # =========================================================================
    up5 = Concatenate(axis = -1)([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(block4), block3])
    block5 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter*4, 3,3)(up5)
    # =========================================================================
    up6 =  Concatenate(axis = -1)([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(block5), block2])
    block6 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter*2, 3,3)(up6)
    # =========================================================================
    up7 =  Concatenate(axis = -1)([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(block6), block1])
    block7 = _conv_bn_relu(nb_filter, 3,3)(up7)
    # =========================================================================
    out_block1 = _conv_bn_relu_x2(nb_filter, 3,3)(block4)
    # =========================================================================
    out_block2 = _conv_bn_relu_x2(nb_filter, 3,3)(block5)
    # =========================================================================
    out_block3 = _conv_bn_relu_x2(nb_filter, 3,3)(block6)
    return out_block1, out_block2, out_block3, block7

def buildMultiModel_U_net(input_dim, lr = 1e-2, dropout = None, loss_fcn = 'mse', activation = 'linear', loss_weights=[1./64,1/16, 1./4, 1]):
    input_ = Input (shape = (input_dim))
    # =========================================================================
    out_block1, out_block2, out_block3, block7 = U_net_Multi_base(input_, dropout)
    # =========================================================================
    aux_output_1 =  Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='orthogonal', activation = activation, name = 'aux1')(out_block1)   
    aux_output_2 =  Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='orthogonal', activation = activation, name = 'aux2')(out_block2)
    aux_output_3 =  Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='orthogonal', activation = activation, name = 'aux3')(out_block3)
    main_output =  Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='orthogonal', activation = activation, name = 'original')(block7)
    # =========================================================================
    model = Model (inputs = input_, outputs = [aux_output_1, aux_output_2, aux_output_3, main_output])
    #opt = SGD(lr = lr, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
    return model
```

**My Training code**

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
self.losses = []

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
def step_decay(epoch):
step = 16
num = epoch // step
if num % 3 == 0:
lrate = 1e-3
elif num % 3 == 1:
lrate = 1e-4
else:
lrate = 1e-5
#lrate = initial_lrate * 1/(1 + decay * (epoch - num * step))
print('Learning rate for epoch {} is {}.'.format(epoch+1, lrate))
return np.float(lrate)

base_path = 'cells/'
data = []
anno = []

def read_data(base_path):
imList = os.listdir(base_path)
for i in range(len(imList)):
if 'cell' in imList[i]:
img1 = plt.imread(os.path.join(base_path,imList[i]))
data.append(img1)

        img2_ = plt.imread(os.path.join(base_path, imList[i][:3] + 'dots.png'))
        img2 = 100.0 * (img2_[:,:,0] > 0)
        img2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img2, sigma=(1, 1), order=0)
        anno.append(img2)
return np.asarray(data, dtype = 'float32'), np.asarray(anno, dtype = 'float32')
def load_data():
data, anno = read_data(base_path)
anno = np.expand_dims(anno, axis = -1)

mean = np.mean(data)
std = np.std(data)
print('Size of dataset = ', len(data[:]))
data_ = (data - mean) / std

train_data = data_[:150]
train_anno = anno[:150]
print('Size of training dataset = ', len(train_data[:]))

val_data = data_[150:]
val_anno = anno[150:]
print('Size of validation dataset = ', len(val_data[:]))
return train_data, train_anno , val_data , val_anno     
def train_(base_path):
#device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

X_train,Y_train, X_val, Y_val = load_data()

print('-'*30)
print('Creating and compiling the fully convolutional regression networks.')
print('-'*30)    

model = buildMultiModel_U_net(input_dim = (256,256,3))
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('cell_counting.hdf5', monitor='loss', save_best_only=True)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(patience=2, monitor='val_loss')
model.summary()
#Plot model architecture
#tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model,
#                       to_file = 'model.pdf',
#                         show_shapes = True,
#                         show_layer_names = True,
#                         rankdir = 'TB',
#                         expand_nested = False,
#                         dpi = 96)
print('...Fitting model...')
print('-'*30)
change_lr = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
time1 = time.time()


def train_model_multi_task(model, X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val, nb_epochs=192, nb_epoch_per_record=1, input_shape=(256,256,3), batch_size =2, is_mae = False, lr_max = None):
    import random
    train_images=np.concatenate([X_train,Y_train],axis= -1)
    val_images=np.concatenate([X_val,Y_val],axis= -1)
    #print(len(train_images))
    print(X_train.shape[0])        
    
    ## train data generator
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center = False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center = False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization = False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization = False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening = False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range = 30,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    width_shift_range = 0.3,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range = 0.3,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    zoom_range = 0.3,
    shear_range = 0.,
    horizontal_flip = True,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip = True, # randomly flip images
    fill_mode = 'constant',
    #validation_split=0.2,
    dim_ordering = 'tf')
    train_datagen.fit(train_images)
    #train_gen=train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 2 )

    ## validation data generator
    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center = False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center = False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization = False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization = False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening = False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range = 30,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    width_shift_range = 0.3,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range = 0.3,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    zoom_range = 0.3,
    shear_range = 0.,
    horizontal_flip = True,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip = True, # randomly flip images
    fill_mode = 'constant',
    #validation_split=0.2,
    dim_ordering = 'tf')
    val_datagen.fit(val_images)
    #val_gen=val_datagen.flow(X_val, Y_val, batch_size = 2)
    
    def multiple_outputs(generator, X, Y):    
        genX = generator.flow(X, Y, seed=7, batch_size = 150)

        while True:
            genXi = genX.next()

            yield genXi[0], [genXi[1],genXi[1], genXi[1], genXi[1]]
        
    train_gen = multiple_outputs(train_datagen, X_train, Y_train, )
    val_gen = multiple_outputs(val_datagen, X_val, Y_val)
    print (train_gen)


# Fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow().
    model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                        steps_per_epoch = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                        epochs = 192,
                        callbacks = [model_checkpoint, change_lr,early_stop],
                        validation_data= val_gen,
                        validation_steps = X_val.shape[0] // batch_size
                       )
train_model_multi_task(model, X_train,X_val,Y_train,Y_val)
model.load_weights('cell_counting.hdf5')
A = model.predict(X_val)
mean_diff = np.average(np.abs(np.sum(np.sum(A,1),1)-np.sum(np.sum(Y_val,1),1))) / (100.0)
```

Comment: Just checking – `axu1`, `aux2`, and `aux3` are the `out_blockN` variables, right? (Want to make sure I'm interpreting the returned layers correctly.) (I'm asking b/c I don't see corresponding labels.)

Comment: Also, where is `_conv_bn_relu_x2` defined? I don't see it anywhere. 

Comment: Sorry mistakenly didn't include  ```_conv_bn_relu_x2```. The post has just been edited. Thanks

Comment: Also, just checking – have you tweaked the `N` you scale `nb_filter` by for `block4`, `block5`, and `block6`? It looks like you're off by a few powers of 2 in each case. (i.e. what have you tried tweaking and what were your results?)

Comment: No.  ```aux1``` is the ``` density_pred_1``` output with ```out_block1``` as input. Similar with ``aux2``` which is``` density_pred_2```  with ```out_block2```  as input  and  ``aux3``` similar.

Comment: I tried tweaking the input shape to (32,32,3) to examine its effect. but the error was something like ``` ValueError: Error when checking target: expected input_8 to have shape (256,256,3) but got array with shape (32,32,3)```

Comment: Also,  I haven't tried tweaking the filters since without the auxiliary layers the UNet model properly worked. Seems there is something I am not doing right with the aux outputs

Comment: for clarity on the outputs. I have also renamed ```density_pred_1``` , ```density_pred_2```, ```density_pred_3``` to ```aux_output_1```, ```aux_output_2```, ```aux_output_3```  respectively while ```main_output``` remains the ```original``` UNet output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UNet – but `aux1` has the smallest size because it's taking the smallest `Conv2D` sequence `block4` and applying further convolutions. It seems you need to undo this with something like `Upsampling2D`. If you look at your `aux2` and `aux3` blocks, they're notably larger, in part, due to the `Upsampling2D` operation that's applied.

This may be helpful in working out what your next steps should be. https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

I'm not sure what your `stride` is for the `_2x` functions either, that likely contributes to output shrinkage, as well.

Comment: Thanks @John. Upsampling the auxiliary output will definitely increase their shape which goes against my initial aim. I want to just apply a 2 CONV2D-RELU block on the intermediate layers  ```block_4```, ```block_5``` and  ```block_6``` to observe what impact introducing these *auxiliary output layers* can have my training. However, I will try Upsampling and see what happens.